# Show that $\mu (X)< \infty$

Tags: measure-theory, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Let $(X,A,\mu)$ be a measure space and $f:X\rightarrow ]0, \infty[$ summable such that $\frac{1}{f}$ is also summable. Show that $\mu (X)< \infty$

What I did was applying cauchy-schwarz inequality on $f$ and $\frac{1}{f}$ ,

$\mu (X)^2=\left ( \int_{X}^{}\left | f \right |\left | \frac{1}{f} \right |d\mu \right )^2\leq \left ( \int_{X}^{}|f|^2d\mu \right )\left ( \int_{X}^{} \frac{1}{|f|^2}d\mu\right )$

How can I continue ? I was thinking of considering cases for $f$ when it is bounded and when not, but I don't know if it's useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apply Cauchy-Schwarz on $\sqrt f$ and $1/\sqrt f$: you will end up with finite integrals by assumption.

Comment: Ohhh, very nice , thank u